# magento - category pages show - "error processing your request"

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

On Magento 1.6.x test site, I was modifying products and categories.
All of a sudden all links to categories (eg: catalog/category/view/s/myCat/id/9/)
gives me ugly -"error processing your request" page.

Re-indexed, cleared cache, even re-started server but message keep coming back.

I tried deleting root category and re-creating a new root category, and sub-categories with products.

Then verified that products are enabled, with inventory, linked to category etc..

Then again verified that new Manage Stores -> Main WebSite -> 'root2 catalog' is linked to Store.

New categories links  appear on home page OK, however still getting error linking to them.
Product pages still works OK.

Nothing in log.

What is next step?

log look like this...

```
a:5:{i:0;s:61:"Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::s(Array
(
)
)";i:1;s:3956:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml(9): Varien_Object->__call('s', Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml(9): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->s()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend\base\d...')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('product_list', true)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Category\View.php(85): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('product_list')
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\category\view.phtml(70): Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View->getProductListHtml()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend\base\d...')
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Text\List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\3columns.phtml(49): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend\base\d...')
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#25 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\controllers\CategoryController.php(159): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#26 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(420): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#27 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#28 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#29 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#30 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#31 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#32 {main}";s:3:"url";s:36:"/magento/index.php/category-2-1.html";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Comment: Without the actual error it is going to be difficult to help you.  Can you grab the error report and paste the exceptions here so we can see the error.  They are located in var/report - or alternatively turn on developer mode and display_errors and you should see the errors on screen

Comment: I posted error... never went there before! Looks like problem in producst/catalog/list.phtml

Comment: have small error in app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\list.ptml

Comment: Can you post the contents of list.phtml? Have you made changes? Looks like it's trying to make a call to a function "s"... I'd hope that's not the name of a function and just a typo.

Comment: i had some bad code in the file. copied in backup and it solved the problem.